# Representation/Modeling of data in Java (Class vs. Instance Variable)

Tags: java, class, modeling, instance-variables

it seems so fundamental that I may miss something, but currently it's more luck than anything else when I look for the correct representation of data.

I'm working on a poker application. E.g. I want to represent a few things like a card, an opponent, or a starting hand (consisting of two cards) an opponent could hold.

Now some data may be more trivial, e.g. a card probably becomes a class with a suit and rank as instance variable. An opponent may probably be modeled as a class as well. For a starting hand it becomes more difficult. Should I model it as an own class, that contains two cards as instance variable, or will it become an array inside the opponent class, that holds two cards?

When do I model something as a class and when as an instance variable inside another class? When do I use collections or arrays, instead of a class? Those could hold multiple data, like classes as well, right?

Is there a right or wrong, or some best practices? I somehow feel lost in the sheer amount of possibilities of modeling the program.

Thank you all
-cobby

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Java Compositions.

Composition is the design technique to implement **has-a** relationship in classes. We can use java inheritance or **Object composition** for **code reuse**.

Java composition is achieved by using instance variables that refers to other objects. For example, a **Person** has a **Job**.

You can find an example for composition [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1325/what-is-composition-in-java-java-composition-example)

In your case, `Hand` has `Card`s. So you should create instance variables for `Card` inside `Hand` class. Ex:

```
class Card{
    //....
}

class Hand{
    private Card card1, card2;
    //....
}
```

Java is a Object-oriented programming(OOP) language. It is a programming paradigm based on the concept of "objects", which are data structures that contain data, in the form of fields, often known as attributes; and code, in the form of procedures, often known as methods.

So you can represent anything in the real world using a class. `Card`, `Hand`, `Player`, `Game` all can be represent as classes. A class is basically a blueprint for an object. It contains the information about how to create that object.

So now the question is **why you should use an Hand class instead of an array?**
Here is why. Lets take an OOP example.

```
class Hand{
    //.....
}

class Player{
    Hand h;
}
```

What are the `Player`'s attributes here? The `Player` has a `Hand`. That is the relationship between the `Player` and the `Hand` classes. It makes perfect sense in the real world too.

Now lets take an array example.

```
class Player{
    int[] s;//s stands for suit
    int[] r;//r stands for rank
}
```

If I didn't put those comments, you will most probably wonder what `s`,`r` is. That is because they do not make sense because they are `int`. `Player`s don't have `int`s in the real world, so it does not make any sense.

Compiler wont complain and it will compile the code no matter what approach we use. But the 1st approach is the OOP approach and it is most understandable.

Comment: And why not simply create a class opponent that holds an array variable with two cards, named hand? Then I basically could "skip" the hand class and save code and keep the program more simple. But this is what I'm not really sure of. When do I prefer a class over other forms of representation?

Comment: As I mentioned in the update, Java is an Object Oriented Language. So it is a better to identify the classes first. We can skip the Hand class, but then the Object Oriented part is not achieved. We want the code to be Object Oriented as much as possible.

Comment: But to me it seems that we're forcing something here. When an array is sufficient, why represent data as a much more complex class? Isn't there more to it?

Comment: What we are forcing is good practice. It is true that you can use an array here. But it is better to use a Hand class because it makes everything easier. I will post an example where implementing a Hand class will be useful rather than using an array.

Comment: @cobby If the whole purpose of the `Player` class is holding cards, then sure you can skip `Hand`. But if `Player` has some other functionality as well (like personal information, score etc.) then it's cleaner to separate the code dealing with cards into its own class.